# Symfony 2 Can't create new bundle despite being able to create several the past few days

Tags: php, symfony

Nothing has changed as far as I can tell. I'm the right directory that I've created the other bundles in. I'm using `php app/console generate:bundle` which usually walks me through the rest of the steps. I'm using Xampp as my apache server. My PHP version is 5.3.24 as is reported by Git Bash when I use the `php --version` command.

Like I said I have several bundles already developed all of which I used the `generate:bundle` command to create but suddenly it isn't working. It doesn't return an error either. It just goes to the next line as if I hadn't given it a command. I can create them manually, but that obviously isn't the most efficient use of my time.

I'm in the directory of my Symfony files as well:

`c/xampp/htdocs/projects/symfony`

I doubt this matters but in the nature of disclosure I'm using PHP Storm as my IDE.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the command tool from PHPStorm ? If so what is your PHPStorm version ?

Comment: I'm not, I'm using Git Bash. Just tried it with PHPStorm command and got exit code 255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an IIS Services conflict. It was serving another PHP install that I didn't even know existed. The joys of working for a university running every Microsoft product they possibly can at all times.